# Extracting URL From Span Element Without href

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am attempting to extract links from a website that does not use a `href`.  I have tried multiple iterations of trying to find the tag associated with the url that from what I can gather is between `<span>` elements.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.flavortownusa.com/locations'

page = requests.get(url)
f = open("test12.csv", "w")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lists = soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item-inner')

for list in lists:
    title = list.find('span', class_ = '$0')
    webs = list.find('#text', class_ = 'fa-fa.link')
    address = list.find('ul', class_ = 'post-meta')
    temp = list.find('span', class_ = 'text')
    temp2 = list.find('i', class_ = '(text)')
    info = [title, webs, address, temp, temp2]
    f.write(str(info))
    f.write("\n")

    print(info)
```

[image: Source]

The desired output is to extract data from `<span></span>` where the 345 40th Ave N and the url below `i class = 'fa fa-link'` and `i class = 'fa fa-phone'` where the three elements are placed into a CSV File

Comment: So you need the name, address and phone number for each listing? What are `temp` and `temp2`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could call next element `e.find(class_ = 'fa-link').next`after selecting the `<i>` with class `fa-link`:

```
for e in lists:
    print(e.find(class_ = 'fa-link').next.strip() if e.find(class_ = 'fa-link') else '')
```

**Note:** *Do not use reserved keywords like `list` and always check if element you are searching for is available.*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.flavortownusa.com/locations'
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')


with open('somefile.csv', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    
    for e in soup.find_all('div', class_ = 'listing-item-inner'):
        title = e.h3.text
        webs = e.select_one('.fa-link').next if e.select_one('.fa-link') else ''
        address = e.span.text
        phone = e.select_one('.fa-phone').next if e.select_one('.fa-phone') else ''

        f.write(','.join([title, webs, address, phone])+'\n')
```